# What controller should i use for this?

Tags: ios, view

Hey guys what controller it is in picture for IOS? Is it table view controller in xcode or something? Please suggest controller to look like this picture.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a `TableView` with custom `tableViewCell`.